# Release software as GPL (or similar) but allow non-GPL Plugins?

Tags: licensing

I am trying to figure this out since a few days now and find no way to do this:
I have a software I want to release under the AGPL so the base system "is open-source", but my software has a plugin interface, where external plugins can be loaded at runtime (so no separation which the GPL would allow).
I now what to make it possible to others to develop non-GPL plugins, as I do not like "this part" of the GPL.

**Is there a ways to somehow allow this as an exception to the GPL or in any other way?

Or is there a license which has the same copyleft for the code itself but permits linked software to be under a different license?**

I already though of releasing the plugin interface under a different license (like LGPL), but to quote a well know CEO: "The GPL is like cancer". This is not possible, as the plugin interface must be GPL, because it is also linked into the (A)GPL'ed main project.

**Could I solve this with some kind of "weird" dual-licensing of the plugin interface?**

P.S.: My software is developed using .net 4.5 and C# if that matters anyhow.

Comment: I wouldn't quote Steve Ballmer.

Comment: Eh.  He's right enough.  If you go GPL, you might as well go GPL *all the way*.  Cause you're going to end up having to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to release the API libraries/assemblies as LGPL, which allows the user to link those in without "tainting" their software, thus the plugins are taint-free, but still requires enhancements to the API libraries to be released.

Comment: Thats actually a great idea - never thouth of that. Do you know how that would apply to reverse engineering (which is easy for .net)? Could someone reverse engineer the LGPL released binarys and modify the code or is this not permitted?

Comment: BUT would this work "the other way around"? Can someone use that plugin in a "self compiled GPL build"?

Comment: Yes.  If the code is runnable without the plugin, it cannot taint stuff that it does not require. Think of the `ls` command.  If I used it to get a directory listing on a proprietary file system that does nothing more than meet the linux API for file systems, would `ls` taint my file system?

Comment: Linux is GPL, and there are commercial kernel modules (plug-in APIs) that are proprietary.